# "Package Installation" error on Visual Studio project load

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio-2013

I wanted to learn ASP.NET MVC web development. So I pulled up a Youtube to give me a tutorial on the basics.

I was able to create the simple project just fine. The next day, I went to create another project to do some practice. However, when I went to create my project, as the project was loading up by adding in the libraries, I get the following 2 errors. So, I went into the filepath specified in the error (Screenshot 3-5). It appears the packages are in their path. So does the error mean the files are corrupt? I'm not sure why I'm getting a "no matching element" error.

Software:  Visual Studio 2013

Framework:  .Net Framework 4.5

Project Type:  ASP.NET Web Application

[image: Error]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]